# Display discount percentage before price in WooCommerce 6 (not On-sale badge) or moving On-sale badge

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I don't use "On-sale badge" because it doesn't display % discount on the main store page and I need to display percentages before the price. I have a code from an old WooCommerce(maybe) it doesn't work, it shows 0%, please help me to rewrite the functions. Or show how to move the "On-sale badge" to one line with the price of the product. tnx

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'ywp_single_price_html', 100, 2 );
function ywp_single_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    $html = $price;

    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $discount = '';

        $regular_price = $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ? $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ) : $product->get_regular_price();
        $sale_price    = $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ? $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true ) : $product->get_sale_price();

        if ( $regular_price && $sale_price ) {
            $html .= ywp_get_sale_percentage( $product );
        }

        if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
            $html = str_replace( '<del>', '<del>M.R.P.: ', $html );
            $html = str_replace( '<ins>', '<ins>Price: ', $html );
        }
    }

    return $html;
}

function ywp_get_sale_percentage( $product ) {
    $max_percentage = 0;
    $save_price     = 0;

    if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        if ( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            $max_percentage = ( ( $product->get_regular_price() - $product->get_sale_price() ) / $product->get_regular_price() ) * 100;
            $save_price     = $product->get_regular_price() - $product->get_sale_price();
        } else {
            foreach ( $product->get_children() as $child_id ) {
                $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id );
                $price     = $variation->get_regular_price();
                $sale      = $variation->get_sale_price();
                $percentage = $price - $sale;

                $percentage = 0;
                if ( $price != 0 && ! empty( $sale ) ) {
                    $percentage = ( $price - $sale ) / $price * 100;
                }
                if ( $percentage > $max_percentage ) {
                    $max_percentage = $percentage;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $discount = '<span class="discount-percent">(' . round( $max_percentage ) . '%)</span>';

    return $discount;
}
```

I searched for this and I found many codes to implement this but all doesn't work for me. I need to do that for simple product and variable product, can someone say how can I implement this. I need to display discount percentage like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9S6u.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if there is a valid sale price ( Difference in Regular/Sale price )

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'ywp_single_price_html', 100, 2 );
function ywp_single_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    $html = $price;

    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $discount = '';

        $regular_price = $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ? $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ) : $product->get_regular_price();
        $sale_price    = $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ? $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true ) : $product->get_sale_price();

        if ( ( $regular_price && $sale_price ) and ($regular_price !== $sale_price) ) {
            $html .= ywp_get_sale_percentage( $product );
        }

        if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
            $html = str_replace( '<del>', '<del>M.R.P.: ', $html );
            $html = str_replace( '<ins>', '<ins>Price: ', $html );
        }
    }

    return $html;
}

function ywp_get_sale_percentage( $product ) {
    $max_percentage = 0;
    $save_price     = 0;

    if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        if ( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            $max_percentage = ( ( $product->get_regular_price() - $product->get_sale_price() ) / $product->get_regular_price() ) * 100;
            $save_price     = $product->get_regular_price() - $product->get_sale_price();
        } else {
            foreach ( $product->get_children() as $child_id ) {
                $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id );
                $price     = $variation->get_regular_price();
                $sale      = $variation->get_sale_price();
                $percentage = $price - $sale;

                $percentage = 0;
                if ( $price != 0 && ! empty( $sale ) ) {
                    $percentage = ( $price - $sale ) / $price * 100;
                }
                if ( $percentage > $max_percentage ) {
                    $max_percentage = $percentage;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $discount = '<span class="discount-percent">(' . round( $max_percentage ) . '%)</span>';

    return $discount;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i added your code, Its not work for me ;(. [link](https://orangeclub.co.il/)

Comment: Please check switching your theme, the code is tested ok with storefront theme